# Need to determine which records are throwing a DBConcurrencyException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

All,

I'm trying to save multiple records back to a database, and would like to use optimistic concurrency (database-wins).  In my model, I have

```
public class MySampleTable
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion{ get; set; }
}
```

In my view, users are able to update multiple records at once, which get passed to my controller.

I have no problem adding and modifying data, but every example I have seen involving DBConcurrencyException assumes that only one record is being updated at a time.  Therefore, is there a way for me to identify if there is a DBConcurrencyException for a specific record, while letting the rest of the records pass through (without having multiple trips to the database)?

```
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
    catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
{
    //How do I know which record(s) throw the exception
}
```

Comment: At first, try to analyze exception in in details.

Comment: That's going to be my next step tomorrow (meaning I will first have to throw a genuine exception), but I was hoping someone has already done this and could point me to some property I could then enumerate through and cast into my entity type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DbConcurrencyException, try trapping the DbUpdateConcurrencyExcelption.  This exposes the Entries property of the exception, which has all the entries that are part of the exception.

```
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    //do something with ex.Entries poperty
}
```

works also for async:

```
try
{
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    //do something with ex.Entries poperty
}
```